# How to ensure version 5.5.* for mysql with puppet?

Tags: centos, mysql, vagrant, version, puppet

How can i ensure that the latest patch version of 5.5 will be installed by the yum installer under CentOS?

```
class { '::mysql::server':
    package_ensure => '5.5.*'
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a yum plugin installed, a block as simple as:

`package { 'mysql-server' :
  ensure => '5.5' ,
}`

should work. You may have to add a repository that includes the package you need through the yum plugin. If there is a specifically named version of the package (for example `mysql55w` in the webtatic repo) then you just need to ensure it is installed:

`package { 'mysql55w' :
  ensure => 'present' ,
}`